# iOS - How to initialize custom UIView with specific Frame from NIB

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xib, init

I am wondering what is the cleanest way to initialize a custom `UIView` with a specific frame.

The `UIView` is designed from a `XIB` file.

**Here is my implementation** :

```
class CustomView : UIView {

    @IBOutlet var outletLabel: UILabel!

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    private func setupView() {

        // Set text for labels
    }
}
```

Here is how I want to initialize it in my ViewController :

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth - 50, height: 70)

let customView = CustomView.init(frame: frame)
```

But it is not working, I have a white UIView without any outlets.

And if I do this instead :

```
// Extension to UIView to load Nib
let customView : CustomView = UIView.fromNib()
```

I can see my `view` from `XIB` file, with its width/height used in the `Interface Builder`.

**What is I want to load the `view` from `XIB` file BUT with specific frame ?**

**Am I missing something about initialization ?**

Comment: You need to show how you are getting your View from the XIB.

Comment: You can't "initialise" with  frame and xib both at the same time, but you can load view from xib and then change it's frame. Although I advice you to keep autolayout as much as possible and avoid changing frame explicitly.

Comment: PS: Why not initialise view with ViewController?

Comment: @MichaelVorontsov This custom UIView is for when the user press a button within the App, it will show a Tooltip. I need to set the view width according to the screen size.

Comment: If you are using storyboards and tooltip position fixed i will advice you to create container view controller, setup constraints as you like and hide it. Then you can show it when needed. If you want too add everythin in the code - again I advice you to instantiate view and then setup it's constraints. Latest SDK make it quite easy to do, but you can make it even more obvious using SnapKit for example https://cocoapods.org/pods/SnapKit I highly recommend to use autolayout as Apple discorage using frames last 4 or 5 years.

Comment: @MichaelVorontsov Actually I am using Auto Layout, with constraints on my custom View for the Tooltip. 
I just set the frame width in code when I init/show the tooltip according to the device and it adjust itself with constraint according to the width (to keep kind of an aspect ratio).
The container ViewController would have been cleaner indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a NibLoading class like:

```
// NibLoadingView.swift
//source:https://gist.github.com/winkelsdorf/16c481f274134718946328b6e2c9a4d8
import UIKit

// Usage: Subclass your UIView from NibLoadView to automatically load a xib with the same name as your class

@IBDesignable
class NibLoadingView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var view: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        nibSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        nibSetup()
    }

    private func nibSetup() {
        backgroundColor = .clear

        view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

        addSubview(view)
    }



    private func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of:self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of:self)), bundle: bundle)
        let nibView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
        nibView.anchorAllEdgesToSuperview()
        return nibView
    }

}

extension UIView {
    func anchorAllEdgesToSuperview() {
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            addSuperviewConstraint(constraint: topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (superview?.topAnchor)!))
            addSuperviewConstraint(constraint: leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (superview?.leftAnchor)!))
            addSuperviewConstraint(constraint: bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (superview?.bottomAnchor)!))
            addSuperviewConstraint(constraint: rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (superview?.rightAnchor)!))
        }
        else {
            for attribute : NSLayoutAttribute in [.left, .top, .right, .bottom] {
                anchorToSuperview(attribute: attribute)
            }
        }
    }

    func anchorToSuperview(attribute: NSLayoutAttribute) {
        addSuperviewConstraint(constraint: NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: attribute, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superview, attribute: attribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    }

    func addSuperviewConstraint(constraint: NSLayoutConstraint) {
        superview?.addConstraint(constraint)
    }
}
```

Then your view will subclass the NibLoadingClass like:

```
class YourUIView: NibLoadingView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Set your XIB class in File's Owner like:
In this case it will be `YourUIView`

[image]

Then instantiate it:

```
let myView = YourUIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width-60, height: 170))
```

Comment: This throws me "required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass of 'NibLoadingView'".

Comment: It works, but kind of complicated for this tiny use case

Comment: Agree with prev. comment. It's definitely bad idea to wrap one view in another just to set it's frame.

Comment: Always open to suggest better code. I'm using for years now and had no problems at all about device compatibility, backward compatibility, new iOS versions or any other issue. But again, everybody's here to learn so any better solution appreciated

Comment: You are a life saver!  I spent a week on this and all I was missing was "view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true". Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

You can create custom class like this...

```
import UIKit

class CustomView: UIView {

class func mainView() -> CustomView {
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "nib", bundle: nil)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! CustomView
    return view
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    let view = CustomView.mainView()
    view.frame = frame
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


}
```

Initialize view where you want...

```
let view = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
self.view.addSubview(view)
```

Comment: This is not working, it obviously throws me a fatal error. But this is exactly the kind of init I want.