# How do I create a custom UIView in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I am trying to create a relatively simple custom view (see below) with a few UISegementedControls on a UIView but I can't seem to get things to work properly.

I create XIB file  for the view and set the File's Owner to the custom class (see below).  I then linked the @IBOutlets by CTRL-Dragging directly from the panel that pops up when right clicking on the File's Owner.

In the code I also set the targets for the UISegmentedControls but these never seem to get called and similarly if I set the isSelectionEnabled the segmented controls never get disabled in the view.

What have I done wrong here ?

[image: Custom view]

```
//
//  ScheduleSelectorView.swift
//  
//
//  .
//  
//

import UIKit

enum ScheduleWeeks: String {
    case week1 = "Week 1",
    week2 = "Week 2",
    week3 = "week 3",
    week4 = "week 4"

    static let allValues = [week1,week2,week3,week4]
}
enum ScheduleDays: String {
    case mon = "Mon",
    tue = "Tue",
    wed = "Wed",
    thu = "Thu",
    fri = "Fri",
    sat = "Sat",
    sun = "Sun"

    static let allValues = [mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun]
}
enum ScheduleAMPM: String {
    case am = "AM",
    pm = "PM"

    static let allValues = [am, pm]
}
@objc
enum ScheduleSelectorValueType: Int {
    case week, day, hour, minute, ampm, none
}

@objc
protocol ScheduleSelectorDelegate {

    /// called when a value is changed in the selector
    @objc
    func valueChanged(type: ScheduleSelectorValueType, value: Any?)
}

@IBDesignable class ScheduleSelectorView: UIView {

    let nibName = "ScheduleSelectorView"

    @IBOutlet var delegate: ScheduleSelectorDelegate?

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var weekSelector: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var daySelector: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var hourSelector: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var minuteSelector: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var ampmSelector: UISegmentedControl!

    var selectors: [UISegmentedControl] = []


    @IBInspectable
    var timeInterval: Int = 15 {
        didSet {
            setupMinuteSelector()
        }
    }

    var isSelectionEnabled: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            for selector in selectors {
                DebugLog("isSelectionEnabled: \(isSelectionEnabled): \(selector.numberOfSegments)")
                selector.isUserInteractionEnabled = isSelectionEnabled
            }
        }
    }
    struct Schedule {
        var week:ScheduleWeeks = .week1
        var day: ScheduleDays = .mon
        var hour: Int = 0
        var minute: Int = 0
        var ampm: ScheduleAMPM = .am

        init() {

        }
        init(week: ScheduleWeeks, day: ScheduleDays, hour: Int, minute: Int, ampm: ScheduleAMPM) {
            self.week = week
            self.day = day
            self.hour = hour
            self.minute = minute
            self.ampm = ampm
        }
    }

    var _schedule = Schedule()

    var schedule: Schedule? {
        return _schedule
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
        DebugLog("init(coder)")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
        DebugLog("init(frame)")
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        // grabs the appropriate bundle
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        return view
    }
    func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(nibName, owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        selectors = [weekSelector, daySelector, hourSelector, minuteSelector, ampmSelector]
        setup()
    }

    func setup(){
        setupWeekSelector()
        setupDaySelector()
        setupHourSelector()
        setupMinuteSelector()

        // Set targets for changes
        self.weekSelector.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectionDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged )
        self.daySelector.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectionDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged )
        self.hourSelector.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectionDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged )
        self.minuteSelector.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectionDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged )
        self.ampmSelector.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectionDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged )
    }
    func setupWeekSelector(){
        DebugLog("setupWeekSelector")
        weekSelector.removeAllSegments()

        for (index, title) in ScheduleWeeks.allValues.enumerated() {
            weekSelector.insertSegment(withTitle: title.rawValue, at: index, animated: true)
        }
    }
    func setupDaySelector(){
        daySelector.removeAllSegments()

        for (index, title) in ScheduleDays.allValues.enumerated() {
            daySelector.insertSegment(withTitle: title.rawValue, at: index, animated: true)
        }
    }
    func setupHourSelector(){
        hourSelector.removeAllSegments()

        for t in 0..<12 {
            hourSelector.insertSegment(withTitle: "\(t)", at: t, animated: true)
        }
    }
    func setupMinuteSelector(){
        minuteSelector?.removeAllSegments()

        for t in stride(from: 0, through: 60, by: timeInterval) {
            minuteSelector?.insertSegment(withTitle: "\(t)", at: t, animated: true)
        }
    }
    @objc func selectionDidChange(_ selector: UISegmentedControl) {

        var type: ScheduleSelectorValueType = .none
        var value: Any? = nil
        let index = selector.selectedSegmentIndex

        switch selector {
        case weekSelector:
            type = .week
            value = ScheduleWeeks.allValues[index]
            _schedule.week = ScheduleWeeks.allValues[index]
        case daySelector:
            type = .day
            value = ScheduleDays.allValues[index]
            _schedule.day = ScheduleDays.allValues[index]
        case hourSelector:
            type = .hour
            value = index
            _schedule.hour = index
        case minuteSelector:
            type = .minute
            value = index
            _schedule.minute = index
        case ampmSelector:
            type = .ampm
            value = ScheduleAMPM.allValues[index]
            _schedule.ampm = ScheduleAMPM.allValues[index]
        default:
            type = .none
        }

        self.delegate?.valueChanged(type: type, value: value)
    }
    var valueString: String {
        let week = (weekSelector.selectedSegmentIndex != UISegmentedControlNoSegment) ? weekSelector.selectedSegmentIndex : 0
        let day = (daySelector.selectedSegmentIndex != UISegmentedControlNoSegment) ? daySelector.selectedSegmentIndex : 0
        let hour = (hourSelector.selectedSegmentIndex != UISegmentedControlNoSegment) ? hourSelector.selectedSegmentIndex : 0
        let minute = (minuteSelector.selectedSegmentIndex != UISegmentedControlNoSegment) ? minuteSelector.selectedSegmentIndex : 0
        let ampm = (ampmSelector.selectedSegmentIndex != UISegmentedControlNoSegment) ? ampmSelector.selectedSegmentIndex : 0
        let selection = "\(ScheduleWeeks.allValues[week]), \(ScheduleDays.allValues[day]) \(hour.padded2):\(minute.padded2) \(ScheduleAMPM.allValues[ampm])"
        return selection
    }
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}

extension UISegmentedControl {

    func setSelectionEnabled(_ enabled: Bool) {

            for i in 0..<self.numberOfSegments {
                self.setEnabled(enabled, forSegmentAt: i)
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I really struggled to find any answers that actually work but finally I managed to get it to work.

I think the main solution comes from the NibLoaderView which I found here.

[iOS - How to initialize custom UIView with specific Frame from NIB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993244/ios-how-to-initialize-custom-uiview-with-specific-frame-from-nib)

But I had to make some changes to get it to work in IB.

```
import UIKit

// Usage: Subclass your UIView from NibLoadView to automatically load a xib with the same name as your class

@IBDesignable
class NibLoadingView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var view: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        nibSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        nibSetup()
    }
    override open func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        nibSetup()
        view?.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    }

    private func nibSetup() {
        backgroundColor = .clear

        view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

        addSubview(view)
        view.anchorAllEdgesToSuperview()
    }

    private func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of:self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of:self)), bundle: bundle)
        let nibView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView

        return nibView
    }

}

extension UIView {
    func anchorAllEdgesToSuperview() {
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            addSuperviewConstraint(constraint: topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (superview?.topAnchor)!))
            addSuperviewConstraint(constraint: leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (superview?.leftAnchor)!))
            addSuperviewConstraint(constraint: bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (superview?.bottomAnchor)!))
            addSuperviewConstraint(constraint: rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (superview?.rightAnchor)!))
        }
        else {
            for attribute : NSLayoutAttribute in [.left, .top, .right, .bottom] {
                anchorToSuperview(attribute: attribute)
            }
        }
    }

    func anchorToSuperview(attribute: NSLayoutAttribute) {
        addSuperviewConstraint(constraint: NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: attribute, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superview, attribute: attribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    }

    func addSuperviewConstraint(constraint: NSLayoutConstraint) {
        superview?.addConstraint(constraint)
    }
}
```

And then in the subclass make sure all you have is the following:

```
@IBDesignable class Designable: NibLoaderView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

I sure hope this saves someone else some time...

If anyone is interested there is a working sample app here

https://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/xcode-9-swift-4-ibdesignables-with-xib/

[image]

Comment: An elegant solution. But I think there a couple of redundant lines in nibSetup(). `view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
  view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true` are not necessary as you undo this in `anchorAllEdgesToSuperview()` anyway. Also the init() methods as shown in the subclass are not necessary, they do nothing anyway.  Unfortunate that there remains an extra UIView in the hierarchy, but still, it solves the problem better than any other solution I can find